# php - DOM and file get content

Tags: php, dom

Which is best for performance usage/usability, "file_get_content" or "DOM LoadHtmlFile" ?

As they both get the html content, what is the optimal situation to use one or the other?

This Also go with the "file_put_content" and "DOM SaveHtmlFile"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was a newbie back when I posted this question. Here is my conclusion at the time I am writing this,

> they both do different things completely. "DOM LoadHtmlFile" is a part
>   of a `DOMDocument` class which is very powerful to manipulate html
>   formatted content, and `file_get_content` is used to get file/http
>   content as a string and manipulate as your wish. On a case scenario if
>   the target content are in html format, depending on needs, if requires
>   heavily change then I would personally use `DomDocument` class. If
>   otherwise, I would just manipulate as a string.